# Can two 12/2 cables be used to wire a 240 electric Fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

[image]. Servicing an electric Fireplace seeing if it's wired correctly

Comment: How much current does this "fireplace" pull? Can you verify that both cables are actually in parallel as you think they are  and not a 1-in/1-out setup?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if it's actually 240V and not 240/120 split-phase.  Difference is, the latter needs a neutral to power loads internal to the machine which need 120V.  The former does not.

240/120 example: an electric oven with an oven light, where the light is a common off-the-shelf 120V incandescent.   To make this oven pure-240V would require the owner to find oddball 240V bulbs, or have an internal transformer to knock down 240 to 120 for the bulb.

240V example: hot water heater or baseboard heater.  They simply do not need 120V for anything.

### All conductors must be in the same physical cable.

For a straight 240V service on a 20A circuit, 12/2 is fine.   There's one small gotcha: 12/2 is only made with black and white conductors.  Thus the white conductor needs to be painted or taped a band of color, to indicate that it is a "hot".  *Previously, the law did not require this if the usage was "obvious", and as a result, many electricans fell into the habit of not ever marking anything.*

Answer (score 1):

The appliance maker would be the person to ask.  Find a model number and call and ask them if the unit actually does specify two individual (parallel) double pole 20A  circuits.